# Validation rule to allow number, decimal and percentage

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I am trying to write a validation rule which will allow only numbers, decimal and % symbol.

Below are the samples i am trying but it is not working. If I put 17.5% it is not working

- Any number upto 100 (0-100)
- Number with % symbol = 0% to 100%
- Decimal    = 0.00% to 100.00%

> !REGEX(Text_Field__c , "[0-9]+(.[0-9])+[%]")

Comment: Can you please edit your question to give more detail about what's not working? What are some inputs that are being invalidated but should be valid, and vice-versa?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

In your regex, you're looking for one or more digits (any number of them), followed by one or more instances of any single character (the period) and a digit, followed by a required percent sign. `17.5%` *should* pass - I'm not sure why it's not. But so would `67534&8(9h6%`. I think you should separate the max value part from the regex part. Try this:

```
!REGEX(Text_Field__c, "[0-9]{1,3}(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?%?") || 
    IF(RIGHT(Text_Field__c,1) = "%", 
        VALUE(LEFT(Text_Field__c,LEN(Text_Field__c)-1)) > 100, 
        VALUE(Text_Field__c) > 100)
```

The regex says to look for at least 1, but not more than 3 digits: `[0-9]{1,3}`. Then a group of characters consisting of a period (which has to be double-escaped with backslashes, once for Salesforce and again for the regex engine) and 1 or 2 instances of a digit: `(\\.[0-9]{1,2})`. The `?` means that whole group should appear once or not at all. And then `%?` matches a percentage mark once, or not at all. Then the IF block checks to make sure that the number part is <= 100.

Comment: You know what they say about solving a problem with regex... :)

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Regex has the same syntax as Java except for escape `\` which has to be transformed as `\\`.
You can test your regex with this tool : https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html
You can also test with Salesforce Apex and anonymous code your regular expression : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm

Concerning your regex, there is several problems.
First, to allow numbers without digits and percent symbol, we have to add a `?` for the digit part and the `%` to indicate that is optional. We have also to escape the dot symbol.
The regex becomes in Java : `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[%]?`
In Salesforce : `[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?[%]?`

Second, to restrict to numbers between 0 and 100, you can add to your validation rule :

```
|| VALUE( SUBSTITUTE(Field__c, '%', '')) < 0 || VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(Field__c, '%', '')) > 100
```

Complete rule :

```
NOT(REGEX(Field__c, '[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?[%]?')) || VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(Field__c, '%', '')) > 100
```

Comment: Your regex will allow more than 2 decimal places, which @learningmode implies isn't wanted, but it's not totally clear. Your Java regex needs to escape the `.` to match a literal decimal point, and then Salesforce needs to escape the escape with an additional backslash, as well. Your use of `SUBSTITUTE()` is smart & better than my string manipulation, but I think the regex ensures that the number is >= 0, so you'd only need the <= 100 test.

Comment: The + only applies to the [0-9] class. The escape symbols have been deleted in my answer. I will correct.
And you are right, testing that the number is >=0 is not necessary.

Comment: right - but yours allows, eg `75.678%`, mine would fail with more than 2 digits after the decimal. Not sure which learningmode is after.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Regex. Use VALUE() in your Validation Rule:

```
!ISNUMBER(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(Field__c), "%",""))
```

Now you can add a line like

```
0 <= VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(Field__c), "%","") <= 100
```

And just put in the right logic or/and bits between them

Comment: I like your thinking! As written, this solution would allow entries like `6%.234 `. You could add `RIGHT(Text_Field__c,1)  != "%" && !ISNUMBER(IF(RIGHT(Text_Field__c,1))` , but then the advantage over the regex diminishes. And if they want to limit the decimal places to 2, I think regex is better.